# Can we set Decode default value as expression value as it is in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am using a Decode function something like this:

```
DECODE ((select country_id from XYZ), 
                    'IT', 'Italy',
                    'JP', 'Japan', 
                    'US', 'United States', country_id);
```

I want it to be behave in such a manner that If country_id is one of these three then it should decode the Id otherwise the default should display the country_id as it is.

Is this possible..??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just *change order* (`Decode` should be within `select`):

```
select Decode(country_id, 
              'IT', 'Italy',
              'JP', 'Japan', 
              'US', 'United States', 
              country_id)
  from XYZ
```